# How to create frames in flask and render the templates into frames

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am beginner in Flask. I am creating a simple search app in flask. And want the output files and their preview to be in same web page using frame concept.
I have to separate html for displaying the output path of searched word and preview of those file paths.
Can somebody help in implementing them to single webpage with frames concept?
My resultant html displaying the output file path,

[html file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcn7y.png)
[html to display resultant file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUOMl.png)

The preview html of result path,
[html to preview the file(resultant file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7DwA.png)

Comment: When you say file, what kind of file is it exactly? image, pdf, spreadsheet?

Comment: It is text files

Comment: Your files have what extension? .txt?

Comment: Yes, its .txt extension

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Both images you have posted contain a relatively small amount of code. Please consider copying and pasting both code snippets in text format into formatted code-blocks in your post. This will likely increase the amount of respondents your question receives and simultaneously make the question more useful for future visitors to SO. Please read the guidelines in SO Help Center, including the section that begins **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask